# NestJS doesn't print log messages anywhere

Tags: typescript, nestjs

This is how I create a logger:

`private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger('Auth Resolver')`

And this is how I use it:

`this.logger.log('Some log message')`

There is not a config or custom logging. Just trying to print a log message from a newly constructed Nest JS application. I looked through the source code of the `Logger` class and saw that it directs all output to `process.stdout` but nothing is printed to the terminal window I run the application.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Stupid question, but you recompiled and restarted your server, right? And you're looking in the same terminal/command prompt that you used to start the server as well, correct?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes, sure :)

Comment: In your `main.ts` do you have something like `logger: false`?

Comment: You probably have `logger: false` or `logger: [subset of logger methods - {log}]` at you logger config.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit were you able to find a solution? I'm currently experiencing the same issue. Other than default Nest logging messages, my own logger messages are never printed.

Comment: @NikitaFedyashev I did nothing special. Both logger and console.log messages started appearing in the terminal window after a few runs.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit Same here

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue, but when I tried with `application/x-www-form-urlencode` option, it printed out the result in the terminal's console.
Try sending data using the above mentioned option or by `application/json`.

```
{
    "username": "abc",
    "password": "xyz"
}
```

You may consider other options like `multer`, `formidable`, `form-parser`, and others.

> I am using Tabbed Postman - REST Client chrome extension.